# change tmp folder for sudo / root command

Tags: tmp

change tmp folder for sudo / root command

in .bashrc file added

```
export TMP=/new/tmp
export TEMP=/new/tmp
export TMPDIR=/new/tmp
```

Also created a symlink for /tmp to new location

apps that i am running without sudo they create temp files in the new location. However, none of sudo programs create there their temp files.

permisions 1777 root:root.

What i must do?

I have tried eg. TMP=/NEWTMP sudo app but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, sudo performs an "env_reset":

```
 By default, the env_reset flag is enabled.  This causes commands to be
 executed with a new, minimal environment.
```

If your local policy permits, you can override this with the `-E` / `--preserve-env` option, ex.

```
$ TMP=/NEWTMP sudo -E sh -c 'echo $TMP'
/NEWTMP
```

or

```
$ TMP=/NEWTMP sudo --preserve-env=TMP sh -c 'echo $TMP'
/NEWTMP
```

Comment: I wanted to move swap files to another place cause space was filled in. I bought new memory, and swapping was very reduced. So, this solved my problem. Thanks. I will vote your answer as a solution without trying out actually...